# Docker - Running watchify inside container does not work

Tags: docker, browserify, watchify

I'm new to docker and trying to build my dev-container. I would like to have running **watchify**(https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchify) for concat files while Im developing.

Docker can manage volumes. I could have **watchify** running on my system but **I would like to put it on docker host**.

I manage to build the container and image.

```
"scripts": {

    "watchjs": "node_modules/.bin/watchify ./public/js/dependencies.js -o ./public/js/all.js",

    "start:dev": "npm run watchjs & node app.js"
 }
```

**When running the container with "npm run start:dev" it just exits.**

**Any idea why this is happening? Can I get running the watchjs and node app on the container?**

This is how Im building the images/containers:

```
# Build your image
docker build -t albertof/blog .

# Docker create container
docker create -P --name blog-container -v ~/Projects/Docker/example:/Blog albertof/blog

# Docker start running container
docker start blog-container
```

And here my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:argon
MAINTAINER XXX ZZZ xxx@zzz.com

# Update libraries and dependencies
# RUN apt-get update -qq

# Install bower
RUN npm install -g bower

# Make folder that contains blog
RUN mkdir -p Blog

# Set up working directory (from now on we are located inside /Blog)
WORKDIR /Blog

# Expose server
EXPOSE 8000

#
#   LEAVE FILES THAT CHANGE OFTEN AT THE END
#   
#   THIS WILL ALLOW DOCKER TO BUILD FASTER
#
#   STEPS WILL BE EXECUTED ALL OVER SINCE THE MOMENT IT FIND DIFFS
#

# Add npm
ADD ./package.json .

# Install dependencies defined in packaje.json
RUN npm install

# Add bower.json
ADD ./bower.json .

# Install bower components
RUN bower install --config.interactive --allow-root

ENTRYPOINT ["npm"]
CMD ["start:dev"]
```

Comment: Could you paste your Dockerfile?

Comment: @JesusRT anything weird?

Comment: Well,  you said that you were executing the containers with that `npm run start:dev` but it seems that you are just executing that command: 'npm start', is it correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Also, it will execute that command from `/Blog` folder, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the blog folder contains all the code. I realised that to exec watchify, since it is installed locally, it needs to be called from `node_modules/.bin/watchify`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103640/discussion-between-kitimenpolku-and-jesusrt).

Comment: This is not that unexpected. Can you try running it with --privileged=true?

Comment: any error messages if you run `docker logs blog-container`?

Comment: Are you using OS X and virtualbox's shared folders?